# Flutter how to group a list from hive database

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been learning flutter for a week now, and I'm stuck with this.

```dart
GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
  useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
  elements: ?????, //<<-------  get List from ExpenseList
  groupBy: (index) => index['dateTime'], // <<------- group by dateTime
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 0, 
    vertical: 0,
  ),
  reverse: true,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ExpenseTile(
    name: value.getAllExpenseList()[index].name,
    amount: value.getAllExpenseList()[index].amount,
    dateTime: value.getAllExpenseList()[index].dateTime,
    deletedTapped: (p0) => deleteExpense(
      value.getAllExpenseList()[index]),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I want to set the `elements:` into my List of Data. I want to know the syntax